# How to run PIP Install command on Jupyter cell

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I thought we could run PIP Install or PIP uninstall by running something like this on the Jupyter cell.

**%pip install myPackage**

But I am prompted for confirmation like this:

**Proceed (y/n)?**

How do I overcome this and run PIP in the cell?

Comment: according to the output  of `pip --help`, there is a `--no-input` option. i would try that

Comment: `pip install -y myPackage`

Comment: Thanks fo the suggestions Paul and PHD. That did not work. Looks like there may be a problem with my env. I will try this again later.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried to install this way instead of using magic?

```
!pip install <package>
```

Generally this shouldn't prompt you to proceed.

BTW which package are you trying to install? I have tried both ways using `!pip` and `%pip`. Using `%pip` didn't ask me to proceed but asked me to restart kernel.

```
%pip install folium

Collecting folium
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/83/e8cb37afc2f016a1cf4caab8d22caf7fe4156c4c15230d8abc9c83547e0c/folium-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from folium) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: branca>=0.3.0 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from folium) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from folium) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.9 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from folium) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\by20064109\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jinja2>=2.9->folium) (1.1.1)
Installing collected packages: folium
Successfully installed folium-0.12.1
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: For those finding the suggestion here to use the exclamation point with the install command, keep in mind that was just a suggestion to see if it helped. In general your experience in modern Jupyter will be smoother if you stick with the modern install commands `%pip install` and `%conda install` as the modern magic commands were added to insure the installations occur in the same environment where the kernel is running. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 3):

```py
!pip install package_name
```

This is the standard way to install package in Jupyter notebook. But its better to make virtual environment and install all the necessary package in that virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Prakash. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.

Comment: This was outdated advice at the time it was written. The magic install commands were added to modern Jupyter around 2019 and were meant to be best practice upon release then as they insure the installation occurs See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic installation commands that insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. The exclamation point doesn't necessarily do that and that's why the magic version was added. ...

Comment: <continued> [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues for certain users depending on how system is set up. The magic install commands seek to eliminate that variability and thus are best practice now (and at the time this answer was written) and will insure a better experience in Jupyter. The same magic commands work in web assembly (WASM)- powered JupyterLite now.

Answer (score 2):

What about `yes` command instead of magic?

```
! yes| pip install myPackage
```

Comment: Thanks Chachay. I tried it. That did not work for me. I got these errors: yes: standard output: Broken pipe
yes: write error

Comment: Do you use `conda`? 
I guess so because I know this package manager asks 'Proceed (y/n)?'. If `conda` runs by `%pip` on your jupyter, `!conda install myPackage -y` can do silent install. 

`pip` doesn't have `--yes` option for `pip install`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chachkay. I apologize for nor acknowledging your help sooner.

Answer (score 2):

From this post https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

```py
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer blondelg. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.

Answer (score 1):

In case the prompt is related to the verification of an ssh key, you should add the host as trusted before running the %pip magic. For example for github

```
import os
os.system('ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer MCMZL. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu using jupyter notebooks, you might need to change the kernel.json file and point it to your python binary path that is in the conda environment:

In ubuntu, you can try this file path and files:

conda environment name:  rag

```
vi ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/rag/kernel.json

which python

/home/user/miniconda3/envs/rag/bin/python

change the python binary path to the one from which python in the active conda environment


vi ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/rag/kernel.json


{
 "argv": [
  "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/rag/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "rag",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
~
```